# Clickable rows for dynamic table generation...help me out

Tags: javascript

I am adding elements to a dynamic table. The issue i am facing is that i need the generated rows as clickable by which i can navigate to a new web page.

Here is my code:

```
//adding rows dynamically after fetching data from table
function addRow() {

        var myName = document.getElementById("name");
        var age = document.getElementById("age");


        var table = document.getElementById("myTableData");

        var rowCount = table.rows.length;
        var row = table.insertRow(rowCount);

       // row.insertCell(0).innerHTML= '<input type="button" value = "Delete" onClick="Javacsript:deleteRow(this)">';

//this is where I fetch the value for the dynamic rows
        row.insertCell(0).innerHTML=myName.value;
        row.insertCell(1).innerHTML= age.value;



    }
```

I am using:

$('#table-name').on('click', 'tr', function() {alert('hello');});

but its not working for me

Comment: When you call this jQuery code? after row insertion or before it?

Comment: In the code you posted the ID of the table is: "myTableData" the jQuery code uses "table-name". Which one is the actual id of your table?

Comment: @ABCD: I am using inserting it after row insertion and table id is "myTableData" and i have to makr row clickable means after clicking on it it should navigate to some other functionality means it will act like a link. That functionality i will implement later.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the following

```
$('#table-name').on('click', 'tr', function() {alert('hello');});
```

The id is not correct, try

```
$('#myTableData').on('click', 'tr', function() {alert('hello');});
```

See working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pa7Zc/)

Comment: Thanks for your help but its not that functionality what i want

Comment: I got the functionality with yuor help actually i was putting that code in the wrong place.........It really heped me

Comment: p:I got the functionality with yuor help actually i was putting that code in the wrong place.........It really heped me